# alerting full url in get request

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a function that will grab content from another url:

```
function loader(url) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $newPosts = $(data).filter(function(){
            return this.id === 'posts';
        }).children();
        });
    };
```

I would like to add an `alert` that will alert the url, **but not the url input variable**

## Reason:

I can input "/page/2" as the url and it will use the domain, so if this is on the domain `www.example.com`, then if I run:

```
loader("/page/2")
```

I want it to alert `http://www.example.com/page/2`

## Question

How can I get the url of a page I am getting content from using `$.get`...again, I do not want to use `url` in the way of getting it.

Comment: Do you mean document.URL !?

Comment: No, I do not mean that...unless I can call that on a document that is being used through `get`. Look at my comment on bfavaretto's answer for more detail

Answer (score 0):

If all your URLs are absolute (start with /), just concatenate with protocol and host:

```
alert(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + url)
```

That's where your request is going when you're calling `loader("/page/2")`.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because the function works, but not on tumblr so I want to see if tumblr maybe did something weird with it since it is not grabbing what i need it to. So I don't want to use `url` at all in this. I need it to grab the place it is grabbing from...I need to see the root domain it goes to in order to check if it is tumblr or my blog. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can't grab HTML from another domain due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) (if that's what you're trying to do).

Comment: It's the same overall domain (tumblr.com), but I need to know if it is searching `http://tumblr.com/page/2` or `http://my_blog_name.tumblr.com/page/2`

Comment: Subdomains are also subject to that policy. And you can't get the URL from the Ajax request or response.